# Guardfile for running single cucumber feature in subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, guard

I have my features organized in subfolders, like this:

```
app/
  features/
     users/
       feature1.feature
       feature2.feature
```

But everytime I save a feature, Guard runs all my features (not just the one that was edited). How can I change it to only run the one that was saved?

Here's my Guardfile for Cucumber:

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb --require features/support --require features/step_definitions" do
  watch(%r{features/.+\.feature})
  watch(%r{features/support/.+})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aph, the answer was right there in the [documentation](https://github.com/guard/guard-cucumber/blob/master/README.md):

> It's very important that you
>   understand how Cucumber gets
>   configured, because it's often the
>   origin of strange behavior of
>   guard-cucumber.
>
> Cucumber uses cucumber.yml for
>   defining profiles of specific run
>   configurations. When you pass
>   configurations through the :cli option
>   but don't include a specific profile
>   with --profile, then the
>   configurations from the default
>   profile are also used.
>
> For example, when you're using the
>   default cucumber.yml generated by
>   cucumber-rails, then the default
>   profile forces guard-cucumber to
>   always run all features, because it
>   appends the features folder.
>
> Configure Cucumber solely from Guard
>
> If you want to configure Cucumber from
>   Guard solely, then you should pass
>   --no-profile to the :cli option.

So, passing in `--no-profile` for the `:cli` option works now, and I'm getting normal behavior.

Shame on me for not reading the docs!

Answer (score 1):

The `--no-profile` flag doesn't seem to be needed anymore, furthermore it results in not displaying any information about the run features to the console (e.g. code snippets for not yet implemented steps), which is definitely not what you want.

Today's way to go seems to be to use `:all_after_pass` flag like this (in your Guardfile):

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => '--drb', :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false do
```

Hope this helps.