# Guard and Cucumber: when I edit a step definition I'd like to only run features that implement this step

Tags: cucumber, bdd, guard

I have read the topic [Guardfile for running single cucumber feature in subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076399/guardfile-for-running-single-cucumber-feature-in-subdirectory), and this works great: when I change a feature, only this will be run by guard.

But in the other direction it doesn't work: when I edit **any step definition file**, always **all** features are run, whether they are using any of the steps in the step definition file, or not.

This is not nice. I'd like to have at least only those features to be run which use any of the steps in the edited file; but even better would be if guard could see which step currently is edited, and then only runs the features that use this specific step.

The first shouldn't be that hard to accomplish, I guess; the second rather seems wishfu thinking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To master Guard and have the perfect setup for your projects and own needs, you have to change the `Guardfile` and configure your [watchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/guard/guard/master/Guard/Watcher) accordingly. The templates that comes with each Guard plugin try to match the most useful behavior for most users, which might differ from your personal preferences.

Each Guard plugin starts with the `guard` DSL method, followed by an options hash to configure the Guard plugin. The options are often different for different Guard plugins and you have to consult the plugin [README](https://github.com/guard/guard-cucumber) for more information.

In between the `guard` block `do ... end` you normally configure your watchers. A watcher must be defined with a [RegExp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html), which describe the files to be watched. I use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test my watchers and you can paste your current features copied from the output from `find features` to have real files to test your RegExp.

The line

```
watch(%r{features/.+\.feature})
```

for example watches for all files in the `features` folder that ends with `.feature`. Since there is no block provided to the watcher, the matched file is passed unmodified to Guard::Cucumber for running.

The watcher

```
watch(%r{features/support/.+})          { 'features' }
```

matches all files in the `features/support` directory and because the block always returns `features`, every time a file within the support directory changes, `features` is passed to Guard::Cucumber and thus all features are exectued.

The last line

```
watch(%r{features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb}) do |m| 
  Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features'
end
```

watches for every file that ends with `_steps.rb` in the `features/step_definitions` dierctory and tries to match a feature for the step definition. Please notice the parenthesis in the RegExp `features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb`. This defines a match group, that is available later in your watcher block. For example, a step definition `features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb` will match and the first match group (`m[1]`) will contain the value `user`.

Now we try to [find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) a matching file in all subdirectories (`**`) that is named `user.feature`. If this is the case then run the first matching file (`[0]`) or if you do not find anything, then run all `features`.

So it looks like you've named your steps different from what the default Guard::Cucucmber Guardfile is expecting, which is totally fine. Just change the watcher to match your naming convention.

Comment: A very useful answer, thanks! I guess I will have to work a bit more with cucumber features and see what's the best way to divide my steps into single files, then I will be able to configure guard the way I want. Best wishes to you!